# How to get a basic knowledge on bifurcation analysis of dynamical systems and on the nature of delay equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matlab

My professor agreed to get me as her research assistant. She asked me to use DDE-biftool in Matlab to find computation of steady state and computation of stability etc. Some examples of the work can be found [here](http://ddebiftool.sourceforge.net/demos/).

My problem is, which the Professor also realizes that I am yet to do courses on Ordinary Differential Equation or Dynamical Systems. So I do not have the basic knowledge of how such analysis takes place.

I hope someone might be able to advise me on how to go forward with this. I do not have problem reading textbooks and teaching myself, but the amount of time I can invest is limited. I wanted to read the Elementary Differential Equation book however, I am not sure if I need to read every chapter or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have absolutely no background in ODE's, reading Strogatz's "[Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0813349109)" coupled with any standard ODE textbook is the most accessible and elementary introduction to bifurcation theory you'll find.

For a more advanced reading into bifurcation theory and nonlinear dynamics that includes delay differential equations with a focus on oscillations, I'd recommend Rand's "[Lecture Notes on Nonlinear Vibrations](http://audiophile.tam.cornell.edu/randdocs/nlvibe52.pdf)".